# laravel 5.2 - date formatting, carbon and Form::date

Tags: laravel, date, output

i have simple columns "date" in my db (date type).
I want to format my date to 'd/m/Y' it works, but not perfect
**this is my model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Report extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'reports';

    /**
    * The database primary key value.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'category_id', 'author_id', 'date'];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id');
    }

    public function getDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
    }
}
```

and inside my **view**:

```
{!! Form::date('date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y'), 
['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
```

Now, on the format create, works ok, but after create record the value is 30/11/-0001 or 00/00/0000, why?

my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required', 'date' => 'required']);

    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $report = new Report($request->all());
    $report->author_id = $user;
    $report->save();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Report added!');

    return redirect('dash/reports');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should store the date in your database as 'Y-m-d' format, just add a mutator and be explicit in your accessor.

```
public function getDateAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->format('d/m/Y');
}

public function setDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->toDateString();
}
```

Comment: now the error is:
The separation symbol could not be found
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data

Comment: @user0111001101 is what?